# Custom UIView: Touch events are not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touch

This question has been asked many times before and I think I've read most of the threads about it but I still can't find the reason for the behavior in my code.

I create my custom UIView (called BView) programmatically like this:

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
_view = [[BView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:_view];
```

When initializing I set UserInteractionEnabled for both the view and the superview to yes and the background color to black, because I've read that some had these problems because their background was transparent:

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.superview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Still the functions to receive touch events are not called:

```
    /* Receive touch events: Touch began */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    bRenderer::log("Touch began");
    [...]
}
/* Receive touch events: Touch moved */
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    bRenderer::log("Touch moved");
    [...]
}
/* Receive touch events: Touch ended */
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    bRenderer::log("Touch ended");
    [...]
    }
```

Somewhere in my project there is also a view controller that receives touch events without problems and I get no errors anywhere in my project. Yet it is quite important to me to receive the touch events in my view instead of the controller. I really don't get what could be wrong here.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'd never, ever add anything to window. That's surely not a good pattern. If you forget to remove it, you'll have an obstacle all the time in your app. No one expects any subviews added there. Really, use viewControllers to manage subviews. Besides, what with patters? Who controls such view? It has no viewController, it breaks MVC. Why do you want it on window? Can you describe? Maybe it may be done another, cleaner way?

Comment: I second that you should add the view to your app in a more reasonable way (like as a subview of your root view controller's view in your root view controller's viewDidLoad method) and update with new code if you still have problems.

Comment: @Vive I wrote a c++ framework for windows that represents the view (it's a 3d renderer). It works on windows and I'm currently porting it to iOS. As I said there is a view controller but it isn't part of the framework. The framework only encapsulates the view. So I do have the MVC pattern but my framework offers an input class on windows and since the controller is given by the user of the framework I want my input class to receive the input from the view (like on windows using GLFW).

Comment: @rschmidt  Where else should I add my view if not the main window? There is no other view in my project and I have to add it somewhere to display it :-D

Comment: @Ben In your AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method you should create a Window object, assign a view controller to that window's rootViewController property, and then call the window's makeKeyAndVisible method. Then you use that root view controller as the ancestor for everything (you can add your touch-detecting view as a subview of its view, or even use your touch-detecting view as its view by overriding the view controller's loadView method)

Comment: @rschmidt Thank you very much. I'll have to change that. Could that be the reason for my view not receiving touch events (maybe the window I've added my view to doesn't support that)? Or is this unrelated?

Comment: @Ben that could well be the reason. The way to properly add a view hierarchy to a window is by setting that window's rootViewController property. If you add views to it in other ways, you can expect "here be dragons" type stuff to occur.

Comment: @rschmidt Alright, it was indeed the problem. Funny thing: I had to change one line of code because (as I wrote before) I had a View Controller and everything else you talked about. Thank you so much.